# Javascript - creating method

Tags: object, methods

I am very new to javascript. I find some sample code for creating a object method.

```
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor){
   this.firstname = firstname;
   this.lastname = lastname;
   this.age = age;
   this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
   this.changeName = changeName;  //Why do I need this? What's it for?
   function changeName(name){
    this.lastname = name;
    }
}
....
</script>
```

My question is: Why do I need to write  `this.changeName = changeName` (also comment above). What's it for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key point is that javascript stores functions in variables. So

```
function changeName(name){
    this.lastname = name;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
changeName = function () {
    this.lastname = name;
}
```

Hence just writing `function changeName(..)...` in the constructor will create a function which is stored in a local variable not a class member variable. To turn it into a class member you need to do `this.changeName = changeName` (notice that this is exactly the same as for other variables).

Typically people add class functions like this:

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor){
   this.firstname = firstname;
   this.lastname = lastname;
   this.age = age;
   this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

person.changeName = function(name) {
    this.lastname = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your class you have a property called changeName and you are passing in a parameter called changeName, by using "this" it will be referenced to the class property and not the parameter that you have passed in.

You don't have to use this, you can do something like:

```
function person(_firstname, _lastname, _age, _eyecolor){
    firstname = _firstname;
    lastname = _lastname;
    age = _age;
    eyecolor = _eyecolor;
    changeName = _changeName;  //Why do I need this? What's it for?

    function changeName(name){
        this.lastname = name;
    }
}
```

So basically by using this, it will just be able to tell apart from the local scope and class scope variables.

Comment: If you mean delete this, you have to make sure your parameters (the variables inside person() are named differently from your class properties

Comment: Oh I mean whether or not I can delete "this.changeName = changeName"?And why or why not. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: Like I said in my post, we use this to say that the class property is equal to the property you passed in, I come from a C# background so it might not work the same but I personally always use "this" just to be on the safe side, there is nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: Actually she isn't passing in a variable called `changeName`, or at least not that I can see.

Comment: Sorry, the function requires a a value for changeName